# How to calculate the solid angle of a spherical rectangle from astronomical angles

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Say I have 2 astronomical angle pairs defining a confined region on the visible hemisphere:

(minAzimuth, minElevation) & (maxAzimuth, maxElevation)

How can we calculate the solid angle of the projected area of the spherical rectangle on the unit sphere?

I assume that azimuth makes little difference and results in a linear multiple: (maxAzimuth - minAzimuth)/(2*Pi).

My intuition tells me that the elevation factor can be computed as: Sin(maxElevation) - Sin(minElevation)

Thus the answer as a proportion of 1 would be:
(Sin(maxElevation) - Sin(minElevation)) * (maxAzimuth - minAzimuth)/(2*Pi).

and for the answer in steradians multiply by 2*Pi.

Is this correct?

Many thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I have edited this question since the original post

Comment: I attempted an answer with Gauss Bonnet, could n't get it again.

Comment: I haven't seen that. I'm not familiar with Gauss Bonnet but I'll look into it,  thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of a “spherical rectangle”? The way you write it, I assume you mean all the points whose azimuth is in one interval and whose relevation is in another. Such a rectangle would not be delimited by great circles. Is that what you want?

Comment: @MvG This is what I want, I have found the answer by integration, I will add now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Yes", the formula in your original question appears to be correct.

Let $S$ be a sphere, $\ell$ a line through the center of $S$, and $C$ the circumscribed cylinder with axis $\ell$. A remarkable theorem of Archimedes asserts that *axial projection away from $\ell$ is area preserving*.

[image: axial projection from a sphere to a circumscribed cylinder]

Assume $S$ is a unit sphere and the region in question is defined by
$$
\theta_{1} \leq \text{Azimuth} \leq \theta_{2},\qquad
\phi_{1} \leq \text{Elevation} \leq \phi_{2}.
$$
The area of the "rectangular" patch on the cylinder, and hence of the "rectangular" patch on the sphere, is
$$
(\theta_{2} - \theta_{1})(\sin\phi_{2} - \sin\phi_{1}).
$$
The fraction of the upper hemisphere covered is, as you initially suspected,
$$
(\theta_{2} - \theta_{1})(\sin\phi_{2} - \sin\phi_{1})/(2\pi).
$$

When you obtained the extra factor of three, is it possible you were computing a *volume*?

Comment: Indeed I was. Thank you - I the volume calculation is referred to in my answer - I have edited it to include the steradians reference. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Having done the volume integration I have found that the actual answer to this question is:

(Sin(maxElevation) - Sin(minElevation)) * (maxAzimuth - minAzimuth)*(1/3) as a solid angle.

So my intuitive answer was correct. As the volume of a hemisphere with radius 1 comes out as 2*Pi/3, so as a proportion of 1 the answer would be:

(Sin(maxElevation) - Sin(minElevation)) * (maxAzimuth - minAzimuth)*(1/3)/(2*Pi/3)) = (Sin(maxElevation) - Sin(minElevation)) * (maxAzimuth - minAzimuth)/(2*Pi) as a proportion of 1. Or simply (Sin(maxElevation) - Sin(minElevation)) * (maxAzimuth - minAzimuth) in steradians.

Comment: (+1) My post and your edit crossed paths; I'll leave my answer in case the diagram is useful. :)

Comment: I did not know about the axial projection theorem. Amazing insight - thank you!